# getGridParam is not a function

Tags: jquery

The HTML:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="m1">Get Selected id's</a>
```

The Function:

```
jQuery("#m1").click( function() { 
     var s; 
     s = jQuery("#list4").getGridParam('selarrrow'); 
     alert(s); 
});
```

I have data in the grid "#list4" but it causes an error: `getGridParam is not a function.`
Please help me sort out the problem. Thanks.

Comment: As far as I know a function called `getGridParam` isn't a part of jQuery core.  Are you using a plugin?

Answer (score 0):

it seems your using the JGRID plugin.

There could be three possible problems:

- Your not calling the `getGridParam` function correctly (wrong number of params).
- Your not importing the JS file related to the library correctly.
- You are calling getGridParam on an object that doesn't support it.

I checked the wiki for JGRID and saw you are using the method correctly.

```
getGridParam    name    mixed value
```

> Returns the value of the requested parameter. name is the name from
>   the options array. If the name is not set, the entry options are
>   returned. For available options, see options.

http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods

This leads my to believe you may be calling the method using a DOM element that is not actually a **#grid**.

Please provide more code to make it easier to help.